# CURL is it possible to intercept parameters?

Tags: curl, token

I have the following code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 20,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://mywebsite.com/request.json?Token=randomstring",
    CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true
]);

$jsonString = curl_exec($ch);
```

The problem is the Token is randomly generated on the submit request. I also don't have the access to the function which generates the token. So I need to intercept it somehow during the post process and add it in `CURLOPT_URL`.

Is there a way to do such thing or  is it impossible? (an XHR solution would be accepted too).

Another option would be, after curl login, to read the request.json response . Since request.json response is generated after login. So that would be CURL logs in and after that goes to read request.json response . Is it possible?

Comment: Call curl two times. First call imitate submit call to get token then after you get token, call again above code.

Comment: The problem is I can't make the call without the token. Or it won't return a response.